# SharePoint PnP provisioning engine: applying provisioning template throws "Access denied" error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, provisioning, office-dev-pnp, c-sharp

I am currently facing a strange behaviour with the *SharePoint provisioning engine*. I am targeting a *SharePoint 2019 on-premise* version. I am quite sure that this problem is related to authentication, but I cannot figure it out.

So, basically, I have the following *C#* code (some parts are omitted):

```
ConnectionManager.cs
---------------------

public ClientContext ConnectAndGetContext()
{
    OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager am = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
    return am.GetADFSUserNameMixedAuthenticatedContext(principalManager.Url, principalManager.Username, principalManager.PasswordStr, principalManager.Domain, principalManager.STS, principalManager.IDP, 60);
}

WebRepository.cs
----------------

public async Task<Web> ProvisionWeb(string template, string templateFolder = "")
{
    try
    {
        ClientContext context = connectionManager.ConnectAndGetContext();
        context.RequestTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
        Web web = context.Web;
        context.Load(web);
        await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();

        string templatePath = $"{pathToTemplatesFolder}{templateFolder}{template}.xml";

        XMLTemplateProvider provider = new XMLFileSystemTemplateProvider(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "");

        ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation ptai = new ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation();
        ptai.ProgressDelegate = delegate (string message, Int32 progress, Int32 total)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"...provisioning: {progress} / {total} - {message}");
        };
        ptai.ClearNavigation = true;

        ProvisioningTemplate provisioningTemplate = provider.GetTemplate(templatePath);
        provisioningTemplate.Connector = new FileSystemConnector($"{pathToTemplatesFolder}{templateFolder}", "");

        web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(provisioningTemplate, ptai); <-- this is where it fails
        await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
        return web;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Every time I run this code, using an account that is referenced as a site collection administrator, site owner, referenced in the root *site collection* as owner, and has even full permissions on the *WebApplication* itself, I encounter the following error:

```
Test Name:  TestWebProvision
Test Outcome:   Failed
Result Message: Assert.IsNotNull failed. Returned Web should not be null
Result StandardOutput:  
...provisioning: 1 / 12 - Initializing engine
...provisioning: 2 / 12 - Regional Settings
...provisioning: 3 / 12 - Supported UI Languages
...provisioning: 4 / 12 - Features
...provisioning: 5 / 12 - List instances
...provisioning: 6 / 12 - List instances
...provisioning: 7 / 12 - Files
...provisioning: 8 / 12 - List instances
...provisioning: 9 / 12 - ClientSidePages
One or more errors occurred.
at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Framework.Provisioning.ObjectHandlers.SiteToTemplateConversion.ApplyRemoteTemplate(Web web, ProvisioningTemplate template, ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation provisioningInfo, Boolean calledFromHierarchy, TokenParser tokenParser)
à Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebExtensions.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(Web web, ProvisioningTemplate template, ProvisioningTemplateApplyingInformation applyingInformation)
à SP19ProvisioningAppDomain.Repository.WebRepository.<ProvisionWeb>d__8.MoveNext() dans ...\WebRepository.cs:ligne 124
OfficeDevPnP.Core
System.Exception: {"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}
at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.ClientSidePage.<GetClientSideWebPartsAsync>d__143.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
à OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.ClientSidePage.<>c__DisplayClass114_0.<AvailableClientSideComponents>b__0()
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}
à OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages.ClientSidePage.<GetClientSideWebPartsAsync>d__143.MoveNext()
```

So, for some reason, it throws the error telling that the account is not authorized to perform this action. What is really odd, is the process always fails when it reaches the *Client Side Pages* part. Everything else seems to work fine.

However, through *PowerShell*, with the exact same account, I can do the following thing targeting the same site:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url TRAGETED_URL -UseWebLogin
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path TEMPLATE_PATH -ClearNavigation
```

It runs perfectly well until the end of the process... then, I can smoothly run my *C#* code without any error.

I think this related to authentication, because it is like the *PowerShell* script "opens the access" for the account, but I may be wrong.

It tried to play around with things like so:

```
ConnectionManager.cs
---------------------

public SharePointOnlineCredentials GetSPOCredentials()
{
    return new SharePointOnlineCredentials(principalManager.Username, principalManager.Password);
}

public NetworkCredential GetNetworkCrendentials()
{
    return new NetworkCredential($@"{principalManager.Domain}\{principalManager.Username}", principalManager.PasswordStr);
}

WebRepository.cs
----------------

public async Task<Web> ProvisionWeb(string template, string templateFolder = "")
{
    try
    {
        ClientContext context = connectionManager.ConnectAndGetContext();
        ...

        context.Credentials = connectionManager.GetNetworkCrendentials();
        // OR
        context.Credentials = connectionManager.GetSPOCredentials()

        web.ApplyProvisioningTemplate(provisioningTemplate, ptai); <-- this is where it fails
        await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
        return web;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        return null;
    }
}
```

...but without more success!

Has anyone encountered such a behaviour?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards,

**EDIT 1**

Using the following code seems to be a workaround:

```
OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager am = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
am.GetWebLoginClientContext(principalManager.Url, null, true);
```

However, it uses the current user, not the desired one.

Comment: Why do you set the `Connector` property after getting the `ProvisioningTemplate`? Isn't it redundant or even harmful in your case?